# Running Protractor Tests with --suite option on WebStorm

Tags: protractor, webstorm

I can not see a way of running a protractor test with common protractor options on WebStorm 2016.3.2 Has anyone run across with this problem.

[image]

Comment: Why did you delete [your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324113/trying-to-transform-synchronous-file-reading-into-an-asynchronous-file-reading-o/41324415#41324415) about reading files with promises after I wrote you an answer explaining how to do exactly what you need with multiple code examples?

Comment: After reading about promises I realized that I misunderstood the concept of promises. The question was misleading and wrong. Sorry. +10 for another questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to use the `Node.js` Run Configuration and point it to the `node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. But I think this option should be considered by WebStorm with Protractor configuration. I hope they will read this.